# Getting HTTP code 403 error while trying to execute Spotfire API services

Tags: java, api, spotfire

I am just trying to call Tibco Spotfire UpdateAnalysisService Web Service through a java program and getting below error while execution:-

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 403: null
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.checkStatusCode(HttpTransportPipe.java:310)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(HttpTransportPipe.java:259)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:217)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:130)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:95)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1121)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1035)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1004)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:862)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:448)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:77)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:147)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.loadAnalysis(Unknown Source)
    at com.nielsen.spotfire.TestServices.main(TestServices.java:49)
```

Coder Reference from:- https://community.tibco.com/wiki/calling-tibco-spotfire-updateanalysisservice-web-service

Actual Code:-

```
public class TestServices {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

try {

            Authenticator myAuth = new Authenticator() 
            {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
                {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("<user>", "<password>".toCharArray());
                }
            };

            Authenticator.setDefault(myAuth);

            UpdateAnalysisServiceImplService test = new UpdateAnalysisServiceImplService(new URL("http://server:<port>/spotfire/ws/pub/UpdateAnalysisService?wsdl"));


            UpdateAnalysis ua = new UpdateAnalysis();
            ua.setPath("/TAM Local Ops Dashboard/DEV/API POC/ANALYSIS_RPD_DATA2");
            test.getUpdateAnalysisServiceImplPort().loadAnalysis(ua);

        } catch (MalformedURLException | UpdateAnalysisServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       

    }

}
```

Can anyone help and let me know why am I getting the error.

Thanks,
Asish

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons for this. What version of the Spotfire Server are you using?

Possible causes:

1. The API isn't enabled (in the server configuration).
2. The user account that you're specifying credentials for isn't a member of the *API User* group.
3. The CSRF protection mechanism has been enabled for the public API (your client does not seem to handle this).

If you have access to the server logs those should give you more details.